# Dependency error trying to install gmodels package

Tags: r

I have tried to install the `gmodels` package several ways in R Studio: Used:

```
Tools > Install Packages...

Downloaded the .gz file from
```

[here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmodels/index.html)

and I am still getting:

```
ERROR: dependency 'gdata' is not available for package 'gmodels'
```

EDIT: 
I added the `dependencies=TRUE` and returned this error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Downloads/gmodels_2.15.4.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: If I remember correctly RStudio has a code generator for that function. You should be able to hit up-arrow right after that failure and then put `,dependencies=TRUE` in the arguments list. The Mac GUI has a little "Include dependencies" check box that I leave checked in their 'Install packages" panel. You should check to see if such a facility is available in RStudio.

Comment: Change your repo.  Or install as a zip.  The repo is down that is set as your default.

Comment: Installed as zip worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you are on Windows (which wasn't obvious before) and you are downloading a tar.gz file which is a source file and you probably don't have the compiler Tools. If you are using the RStudio dropdown for "package archive" in the Install panel\, you should switch to the "Repository (CRAN)" selection so that RStudio will go and get the binary versions of the package.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. On Windows. And I tried that already, which gave me: "gmodels is unavailable"

Comment: Use a repository that is more complete.